# How do I extend a model in a UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I would like to understand how to write proper user controls/viewmodels in WPF. To keep things simple, I invented the following example:

Say, we have a `DateRange` class, defined as:

```cs
using System;

namespace MyDateApp
{
public class DateRange
{
    public DateTime Start
    {
        get;
        set;
    } = new DateTime();
    public int Length // in days
    {
        get;
        set;
    } = 0;
}
}
```

(For the sake of argument, we assume that this class cannot be modified in any way.)

An instance of the class is used as the data context of our window:

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace MyDateApp
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DateRange range = new DateRange();
        range.Start = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1);
        range.Length = 5;
        DataContext = range;
    }
}
}
```

I would like to implement a custom view/control, which allows users of the application to choose a start and an end date, instead of a start date and a range. It will be wrapped in a `UserControl` called `DateControl`:

```xml
<Window x:Class="MyDateApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyDateApp">
    <StackPanel>
        <local:DateControl Range="{Binding}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

I was to able to get a basic implementation of this `DateControl` working:

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MyDateApp
{
public partial class DateControl : UserControl
{
    public DateControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public DateRange Range
    {
        get { return (DateRange)GetValue(RangeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RangeProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RangeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Range", typeof(DateRange), typeof(DateControl), new PropertyMetadata(new DateRange()));
    public DateTime End
    {
        get => Range.Start + new TimeSpan(Range.Length, 0, 0, 0);
        set => Range.Length = (value - Range.Start).Days;
    }
}
}
```

With the following XAML:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="MyDateApp.DateControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyDateApp"
             Name="UserControl">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="From:" />
        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Range.Start, ElementName=UserControl}" />
        <TextBlock Text="To:" />
        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding End, ElementName=UserControl}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

It works perfectly for the start date, however the value for the end date is wrong. Thus, my question:

*How can I properly implement this?*

My conditions of success are:

- the original model class has to stay unmodified,
- and the user control has to update the main window data context.

**Bonus:** *What do I have to implement in order to use this control as a `ListBoxItem`?*

Comment: The DataContext is passed automatically to your UserControl. There is no need for a dependency property. So you can simply bind to the properties Start and End in your ViewModel

Comment: Answering your condition: "the original model class has to stay unmodified," Then maybe inherit from the model. Keep the UI as stupid as possible. Otherwise you always depend on your UI for business logic. Second: This is not your model but your viewmodel.

Comment: @Klamsi What do you mean with "The DataContext is passed automatically to your UserControl."? I can just do the `<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Range.Start, ElementName=UserControl}" />` without binding in the main window?

Comment: @Klamsi I guess a separation would be nice, but my business logic has to live somewhere... I am not sure how I would execute your idea.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view model that sits in between the view and the model and bind the controls in the view to the view model instead of binding directly to the view, e.g.:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    //error handling and validation omitted for brevity...

    private readonly DateRange _model = new DateRange();

    private DateTime _startDate;
    public DateTime StartDate
    {
        get
        {
            return _model.Start;
        }
        set 
        {
            _model.Start = value;
        }
    }

    private DateTime _endDate;
    public DateTime EndDate
    {
        get { return _endDate; }
        set 
        { 
            _endDate = value;
            _model.Length = (int)_endDate.Date.Subtract(_startDate.Date).TotalDays;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes sense so far, but how would I plug in this viewmodel with the rest of the code such that it works? Especially, what is the XAML supposed to look like?

Comment: The controls in the XAML can just bind to the view model properties. Or bind the control properties to the view model properties and the controls to the control properties: `<local:DateControl Start="{Binding StartDate}" ... />`

Comment: Yes, but I somewhere have to convert from my model to my viewmodel. Where do I do that?

Comment: The view model has a reference to an instance of the model and handles the "conversion". The view doesn't know about the model.

Comment: Ah. Yes. You are right! However, this would not work with a `List<DateRange>` list because the data is "bound" inside the viewmodel?

Comment: `List<DateRange>`? Where does this come from? I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's often a bad idea to expose a model directly to a view.

This includes the approach which "wraps" model properties.

This will work OK for trivial applications but you will find numerous edge cases that make it unattractive.
EG your user edits a model class.
This fails validation.
You now have bad data in your model.
It is also rather clunky.

I recommend thinking in terms of your model class as a DTO.

Build a viewmodel with corresponding properties and the extra ones you will inevitably require.

Instantiate that viewmodel and copy the data from your model to present it to the view.

database > model > Viewmodel > View

When editing/inserting do the reverse and instantiate a model to pass back to your repository or say entity framework.

View > Viewmodel > model > database

This way your dataannotations can happily live in the viewmodel without polluting the model. This is particularly handy if you're using ORM such as entity framework.

For particularly complicated scenarios you might even want another layer of classes for domain specific logic.

For direct copying of properties, consider automapper.

https://automapper.org/

Edit:

With this approach the viewmodel is totally disconnected from the model so the view isn't going to change it. Thus satisfying requirement 1.

The viewmodel for this should be instantiated by the mainwindowviewmodel as a private member. A public property of the mainwindow would be set to an instance. For a list, the property would be a list or observablecollection of these viewmodels.

I would consider removing the dependency properties in your usercontrol and instead putting the logic into the new viewmodel.

I don't follow what that logic is exactly but I would hope you're not going to raise a question per viewmodel you design and any answer here should show the principle.

Hence the viewmodel might look something like:

```
public class DateRangeViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public DateRangeViewModel(DateTime _datefrom, int _length)
    {
        length = _length;
        fromDate = _datefrom;
        setUpDate();
    }
    private void setUpDate()
    {
        ToDate = ((DateTime)fromDate).AddDays(length);
    }

    private int length = 0;

    public int Length
    {
        get => length;
        set { setUpDate(); SetProperty(ref length, value, nameof(Length)); }
    }
    private DateTime? fromDate;

    public DateTime? FromDate
    {
        get => fromDate;
        set => SetProperty(ref fromDate, value, nameof(FromDate));
    }

    private DateTime? toDate;

    public DateTime? ToDate
    {
        get => toDate;
        set { setUpDate(); SetProperty(ref fromDate, value, nameof(ToDate)); }
    }
 }
```

Your windowviewmodel reads your data, that comes from wherever you get it as the model.

For each you new up a DateRangeViewModel, passing in fromdate and length properties to ctor.

Comment: I encountered the basic gist of what you are saying before. However, my problem is that while I might understand it on a conceptual level, I cannot put it into code. There are all these little implementation details that are left out by the video creators and blogs authors. These might in fact be trivial, but not having seen them implement before, I fail at really understanding these concepts. Thus, could please put your writing in code that solves my particular example.

Comment: The best tutorial I have found so far is from "Angelsix" (youtube). He made a series about WPF UI Programming.